# How to test method retry on optimistic locking without getting an inifite loop?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm using optimistic locking, and when there is a failure on updating my object, I aim to retry the query until it passes. My problem is that the rescue section is never used on the rspec tests.

The method I'm talking about is the following:

```
def create_transaction
  amount = -1 * cost_per_word * word_count
  transaction = Transaction.new(amount: amount, processor: :job_done)
  transaction.service = service
  transaction.job = self
  transaction.save!
rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
  sleep rand
  reload
  retry
end
```

The StaleObjectError is generated on `transaction.save!`, which have a `before_create` hook which edits other object (in this case, removing money from the object account).

To test it, I could, for example, stub `Transaction.new` to raise an `StaleObjectError`, however it would generate an infinite loop.

I also can't test with an approach like

```
p1 = Person.find(1)
p2 = Person.find(1)

p1.first_name = "Michael"
p1.save

p2.first_name = "should fail"
p2.save # Raises a ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
```

Because I'm not testing the `before_save` hook, I'm testing the `create_transaction` method. (thanks to @screenmutt for the example)

How can I properly test the rescue section?

Comment: Why the stubbing doesn't seem correct? That's what I would do, more or less.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would rather find an approach where the error is really generated, if possible. What if my code never throws StableObjectError by itself?

Comment: These are two different tests: testing that the error can be raised and testing that it, if raised, is handled properly.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so perhaps my question is how to test if the error can be raised?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I can't stub because it would lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I need to be able to test is the `unstub` method, cited in [this answer by Chris Heald](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369010/stub-method-only-on-the-first-call-with-rspec)

Answer (score 1):

First, A `StaleObjectError` will **not** be raised when creating an object. It may be raised when editing. [See the Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html)

```
p1 = Person.find(1)
p2 = Person.find(1)

p1.first_name = "Michael"
p1.save

p2.first_name = "should fail"
p2.save # Raises a ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
```

---

**Testing the Rescue Block**

That is what stubs are for, returning a specific value from a method which you may not normally see.

You could also stub `save!`

[RSpec Simple Stub Documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-with-a-simple-return-value)

Comment: Thanks, the stale object error happens on other model, in a before_save hook on transaction model (the transaction removes or add money in the other model balance), so I can't use this straight-forward approach. Sorry, I didn't make it clear on the question, let me edit it.

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to time a `StaleObjectError` if it happens in a before save. Unless you could delay the method's save somehow.